# Developing a simple calculator using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, mobile-application

I am trying to develop a simple calculator which has only add and subtraction functions using Andriod Studion. But when I run it all the elements are overlapping. I have attached a screenshot to get more clear idea about my problem. I really appreciate if anyone can tell me why I got this and how to fixed it.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLWm5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Actually you are not using the layouts properly. I will suggest you
  to learn the layouts properly then you will not face such issues.

Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <TextView
android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/first_number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/second_number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text2"
        android:hint="Enter First Number" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText2"
        android:text="@string/answer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text3"
        android:hint="Enter First Number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your support. Thank you.